# Google TableChart does not play well with other charts on page

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I need to have a google table chart coexist with one other google chart on the same page, but alas this is not happening.  I am using only demo code bits, I can get any other google charts to coexist on the same page but not a table chart.  There have been several questions asked and answered with other chart types but not table chart.  It appears to be a bug for this chart. I use the 'current' version to google charts which I believe to be 43 as of 7/15/2016.

The error will occur on the line towards the end of the code block at the line;
"var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));"

where the exception is;
"Unhandled exception at line 51, column 13 in http://localhost:62064/test.html
0x800a01bd - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this action"

---code begins, this is a complete example web page for the problem---

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>My Test Google Charts Page</title>
    <!--Include for chart support-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load("current", { packages: ["corechart"] });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

        function drawChart() {
                        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                        ['ID', 'X', 'Y', 'Temperature'],
                        ['', 80, 167, 120],
                        ['', 79, 136, 130],
                        ['', 78, 184, 50],
                        ['', 72, 278, 230],
                        ['', 81, 200, 210],
                        ['', 72, 170, 100],
                        ['', 68, 477, 80]
                    ]);

                    var options = {
                        colorAxis: { colors: ['yellow', 'red'] }
                    };

                    var chart = new google.visualization.BubbleChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                    chart.draw(data, options);
                }

                function drawTable() {
                    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                    //debugger;
                    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
                    data.addColumn('number', 'Salary');
                    data.addColumn('boolean', 'Full Time Employee');
                    data.addRows([
                      ['Mike', { v: 10000, f: '$10,000' }, true],
                      ['Jim', { v: 8000, f: '$8,000' }, false],
                      ['Alice', { v: 12500, f: '$12,500' }, true],
                      ['Bob', { v: 7000, f: '$7,000' }, true]
                    ]);

                    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
                    table.draw(data, { showRowNumber: true, width: '100%' });
                }
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <!--Table and divs that hold the pie charts-->
        <table class="columns">
            <tr>
                <td><div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td><div id="table_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </body>
    </html>
```

---code ends--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need for `setOnLoadCallback` for each chart,
this should only be called once per page anyway...

here, I include the `callback` in the `load` statement,
which draws both charts...

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['ID', 'X', 'Y', 'Temperature'],
      ['', 80, 167, 120],
      ['', 79, 136, 130],
      ['', 78, 184, 50],
      ['', 72, 278, 230],
      ['', 81, 200, 210],
      ['', 72, 170, 100],
      ['', 68, 477, 80]
    ]);

    var options = {
      colorAxis: { colors: ['yellow', 'red'] }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.BubbleChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    //debugger;
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Salary');
    data.addColumn('boolean', 'Full Time Employee');
    data.addRows([
      ['Mike', { v: 10000, f: '$10,000' }, true],
      ['Jim', { v: 8000, f: '$8,000' }, false],
      ['Alice', { v: 12500, f: '$12,500' }, true],
      ['Bob', { v: 7000, f: '$7,000' }, true]
    ]);

    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
    table.draw(data, { showRowNumber: true, width: '100%' });
  },
  packages: ['corechart', 'table']
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<table class="columns">
  <tr>
    <td><div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div id="table_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```